# traversing a maze from a starting point and print after each step

Tags: java, data-structures, project, projects-and-solutions

I need help with my code so that I can traverse a maze from a starting point and printing out each step
        the code here will traverse the maze

```
 public boolean solveMaze(int row, int col){
 boolean done = false;
 if (valid(row, col))      {       
     if(MazeArr[row][col] =='E')      
     done = true;  // the maze is solved 

  else  {    
     done = solveMaze(row+1, col);     // down    
     if (!done)               
         done = solveMaze(row, col+1);  // right     
     if (!done)              
         done = solveMaze(row-1, col);  // up 
     if (!done)    
         done = solveMaze(row, col-1);  // left
     if(!done)
         done= backtrack(row,col); //backtracks

     } 
          if (done) // this location is part of the final path     

                MazeArr[row][col] = PATH;  


 }

 return done; 
 }
```

this one checks if the indices are valid 
    private boolean valid(int row, int column)

```
{      boolean result = false;

// check if cell is in the bounds of the matrix
if (row >= 0 && row < MazeArr.length &&column >= 0 && 
                                    column <MazeArr[row].length)
 // check if cell is not blocked and not previously tried         
if (MazeArr[row][column] ==' '|| MazeArr[row][column] =='E')           
    result = true;
   return result;   }
```

this one backtracks whenever the maze reaches a dead end

```
//backtracks the trace
public boolean backtrack(int row, int col){
    boolean checkpoint=true;
    DLLBasedStack<Integer> stackRow = new DLLBasedStack<>();
    DLLBasedStack<Integer> stackCol = new DLLBasedStack<>();
    if ((MazeArr[row+1][col]==' ' && MazeArr[row-1][col]==' ')|| (MazeArr[row][col+1]==' ' && MazeArr[row][col-1]==' ')|| MazeArr[row][col]=='S') 
        checkpoint=false;
    stackRow.push(row);
    stackCol.push(col);

    int r=stackRow.pop();
    int c= stackRow.pop();
    if(!valid(row,col))
        checkpoint=true;
    solveMaze(r,c);      
    returncheckpoint;
}
```

Comment: A cool trick is if you always turn left in a maze, you will eventually reach the finish line.  I have no idea what you are asking by the way.

Comment: You dropped some code on us (very **lazily** formatted by the way!) ... but now what: you expect us to review that; or identify some bug you observe but didn't mind telling us about?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you. In your case I don't understand your problem ? What do you want ? You have to understand that we spend time to help each other, but you have to explain us your problem. We can't spend time to find the problem.